# Do I need a visa to travel to Singapore with a US refugee travel document?

Tags: visas, singapore, refugees

Do i need a visa to travel to Singapore with a US refugee travel document?
I have a refugee travel document issued by US CIS. I am planning to travel to Singapore and I would like to know if I can travel with it and without a visa?

Comment: Is the *Singaporean-citizens* tag correct? You can input your proposed itinerary here https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ to check requirements for yourself

Answer (score 3):

*You need a visa.*

According to the website of the Singapore Immigration & Checkpoints Authority https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-depart/entry_requirements/visa_requirements anyone travelling on a Refugee travel document needs a visa. This type of travel document is subject to assessment of recognition for entry into Singapore.